# How to apply a change to multiple view controllers at once?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

What is the best way to (for example) include a line in multiple View Controllers at once (for example, include a line of code just under ViewDidLoad in every single VC) ?

I'm just looking for a more efficient method than just copy-pasting in 10 different VCs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inheritance will help you:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // your settings for all view controllers here:
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
}

class HomeViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // call code from BaseViewController.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class ChatViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // call code from BaseViewController.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class ProfileViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // call code from BaseViewController.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Another option is Swift extensions:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func configureView() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    }
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView()
    }
}

class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView()
    }
}

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView()
    }
}
```

More about [Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) and [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) in Swift book

Comment: Just want to note really quick that this same method can also be used with Objective-C. This is probably one of the most useful and best kept secrets of creating an app very quickly using programmatic views. This is usually never talked about, not sure why, but I'm glad you posted this answer. Very very important and useful stuff and this isn't limited to UIViewControllers alone.